# How do I unite the two Bedrockium fluids?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

Tinkers Construct has Bedrockium parts (that you can't obtain I think?). ExtraTiC with ExtraUtilities also adds Bedrockium, but it is slightly different. I would like to make it such that smelting Bedrockium gives the TiCon fluid instead of the ExtraTiC one. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Like, should I just disable ExtraUtilities support in ExtraTiC? There seems to be some support in TiCon itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite smelting recipes with MineTweaker + modTweaker.

Read up on how to use Minetweaker here:
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/wiki/Main_Page

The modtweaker documentation for Tinker's construct is here:
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/wiki/ModTweaker:TConstruct_Support

You can download them here if you don't have them yet
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/downloads.html
http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/220954-modtweaker

You would have to remove the recipe that makes the bad liquid bedrock from bedrockium. Then add one to make the kind you want from bedrockium.

Comment: I tried to get this working in game so I could just write the script for you, but the smelter didn't melt bedrockium at all and I saw no sign of bedrock TC parts in NEI. If you give me a list of all involved mods and their versions I'll try again.

Comment: Bedrockium from ExtraUtilities

Comment: I have an instance with No form of liquid bedrock or bedrock tools available. ExtraTic, ExtraUtilities and TiCon are installed. Could you try  installing minetweaker and Modtweaker, then  running /mt liquids and posting your minetweaker.log here. That should make the sources and identities of the liquids clear.